# What did Mikasa say when she was correcting Armin after Eren mastered the ODM gear?

Tags: attack-on-titan

After Eren masters the ODM gear (anime ep. 3 - 21:40~, manga vol. 4), Mikasa corrects Armin by saying, (in the English manga)

> He's relieved because now he doesn't have to be separated from me.

Is this the correct dialogue because there are other translations as well, one of them being

> He's thinking about how he won't have to stay close to me

I'm just wondering which one is correct.

Comment: just to confirm are you talking about the anime or the manga? you say *"Episode 3"* in the question title but when you say *"in the English Manga"* in the question body and generally manga doesn't have "episodes"

Comment: @Memor-X  In a way I am referring to both, since there are different translations between the U.S. manga and Japanese manga and different translations between the dubbed and subbed anime. I just inputted episode 3 of the anime since that's where the scene is, for the manga its volume 4,  but since there are so many different and wacky translations for this scene, I was wondering which one was correct xD

Answer (score 4):

This is the conversation in episode 3:

> アルミン: 目で「どうだ！」って言っているよ。
> ミカサ　: 違う。
> アルミン: えっ？
> ミカサ　: これで私と離れずにすんだと思って安心してる。

Literally, it translates to

> Armin: (His; Eren's) eyes are telling "How's that!".
> Mikasa: (You're) wrong.
> Armin: Eh?
> Mikasa: With this, (He; Eren's) relieved thinking that (he) doesn't have to be separated from me.
>
> <sup>The word in (parentheses) is the omitted subject.</sup>

Mikasa's words is a response to the conversation in dining scene (which was slightly omitted in the anime)

From [post no. 382 on 2chan](http://shingeki-kyojin.com/archives/27011118.html),

> When Mikasa told Eren, "You shouldn't aim to be a soldier anymore",
>
> Eren, who couldn't dispute it, was staring at Mikasa annoyed while thinking "I understand even if you didn't say it!".
>
> **Mikasa misunderstood Eren's expression as "Looking from his staring, he hates to be separated from me".**

Answer (score 1):

In the English anime, it says

> Armin: Look, his eyes are saying, "check me out".
>   Mikasa: They're not. His eyes are saying he doesn't have to leave me. Not anymore.